# nftables Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory with official Debian Wiki

Tags: nftables

I'm following the [official Debian Wiki tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN) for setting up a VPN server on Debian 11.

Everything worked well except for the paragraph `Forward traffic to provide access to the Internet` at the end.

The following lines do not work :

```
IF_MAIN=eth0
IF_TUNNEL=tun0
YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET=10.9.8.0/24
#YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET=10.8.0.0/16 # if using server.conf from sample-server-config
nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "$IF_MAIN" oifname "$IF_TUNNEL" ct state related,established counter accept
nft add rule ip filter FORWARD oifname "$IF_MAIN" ip saddr $YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET counter accept
nft add rule ip nat POSTROUTING oifname "$IF_MAIN" ip saddr $YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET counter masquerad
```

Here is the output :

```
root@server:/home/user# nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "$IF_MAIN" oifname "$IF_TUNNEL" ct state related,established counter accept
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname enp1s0 oifname tun0 ct state related,established counter accept
            ^^^^^^
```

I get similar error with the 3 commands.
Do I have missing something ? Is something missing in the tutorial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Debian Wiki's instructions have been written to build on top of the compatibility tables and chains created by `iptables-nft` (or possibly the default stub `/etc/nftables.conf` included in the `nftables` package), which is the default version of `iptables` on Debian 10 and newer.

If you are starting from a completely blank `nftables` configuration, you must first create the tables and chains before adding rules into them:

```
IF_MAIN=eth0
IF_TUNNEL=tun0
YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET=10.9.8.0/24

# Create a rules table for IPv4, named "custom":
nft create table ip custom

# Create a forward filter chain with the standard priority and 
# iptables-resembling name "FORWARD", into the "custom" table 
# created above:
# (priority filter == priority 0, see "man nft")
nft add chain ip custom FORWARD { type filter hook forward priority filter\; }

# Create a NAT filter chain with the iptables-like name "POSTROUTING" too:
nft add chain ip custom POSTROUTING { type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat\; }

# now you can start adding your filter rules
nft add rule ip custom FORWARD iifname "$IF_MAIN" oifname "$IF_TUNNEL" ct state related,established counter accept
nft add rule ip custom FORWARD oifname "$IF_MAIN" ip saddr $YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET counter accept
nft add rule ip custom POSTROUTING oifname "$IF_MAIN" ip saddr $YOUR_OPENVPN_SUBNET counter masquerade
```

This places all your custom rules into a single table named `custom`. If you later add some other software that creates nftables rules of their own, they are likely to use their own table(s), which should remove the possibility of them wiping out your custom rules by accident. You'll just need to review the hook priorities to ensure a sensible processing order of the rule chains in different tables, and adjust if necessary.

Note: `custom`, `FORWARD` and `POSTROUTING` here are just names you could change to whatever you want, while everything else has a specific meaning.

This also allows you to delete or temporarily deactivate all your custom rules at once, with a single command:

```
nft add table ip custom { flags dormant; } # temporary disable
nft add table ip custom       # re-enable
nft delete table ip custom    # wipe custom rules completely
```

These might be helpful when troubleshooting your ruleset.

To make the rules persistent:

```
nft list ruleset > /etc/nftables.conf  # save the current rules
systemctl enable nftables.service      # enable loading rules at boot
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make it persistent after reboot ?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

`nftables` does *not* contain any tables or rules by default, you need to create them manually.

Please follow the manual here:

https://wiki.debian.org/nftables#new_syntax